# Removing backspace characters from sshseclib log output lines in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a function that connect to a network device through ssh and perform some functions, the problem is when the line is too long, it comes full with backspace char and repeated parts, I'm trying to format to be human readable. I store this lines in array and they are delivered through json. Below is an example:

```
$log .= $configure->exec("security-mng 1 state enable mode permit ingress-type iphost 1 protocol web telnet");
```

and the output from it:

```
OLT-235(gpon-onu-mng)#security-mng 1 state enable mode permit ingress-type iph\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b$g 1 state enable mode permit ingress-type iph           \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bo          \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bs         \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bt        \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b        \b\b\b\b\b\b\b1      \b\b\b\b\b\b      \b\b\b\b\bp    \b\b\b\br   \b\b\bo  \b\bt\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b$enable mode permit ingress-type iphost 1 prot           \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bo          \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bc         \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bo        \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bl       \b\b\b\b\b\b\b       \b\b\b\b\b\bw     \b\b\b\b\be    \b\b\b\bb   \b\b\b   \b\bt\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b$e permit ingress-type iphost 1 protocol web t           \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\be          \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bl         \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bn        \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\be       \b\b\b\b\b\b\bt      \b\b\b\b\b\b\r\n
```

I managed to get rid of the \b and double spaces through preg_replace("/\s\s|[[:^print:]]/", "",), but this does not solve the problem because there are the repeated parts. Below is the output without backspace char and double space, but as I say this does not solve the real problem that is the repeated parts:

```
OLT-235(gpon-onu-mng)#security-mng 1 state enable mode permit ingress-type iph$g 1 state enable mode permit ingress-type iph os t1pr ot$enable mode permit ingress-type iphost 1 prot oc ol  w eb  t$e permit ingress-type iphost 1 protocol web t el ne t
```

Comment: Is this sshseclib?

Comment: Yes, it is. It's a known bug?

Comment: you want output like this  --> https://regex101.com/r/FHpzqx/1/ ?

Comment: this solves the \b and double spaces like I am doing with /\s\s|[[:^print:]]/
but the problem is that there are repeated parts because the backspace char really should mean a backspace i think.

Answer (score 0):

1. The \b sequences are not really telling how many characters do we have to strip.
2. Also removing all of them will leave you with remaining spaces whom you won't be able to tell if they have to be stripped or not.

This piece of code shows what happens when we try those two approaches:

```
<?php
$log_line = <<<'EOF'
OLT-235(gpon-onu-mng)#security-mng 1 state enable mode permit ingress-type iph\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b$g 1 state enable mode permit ingress-type iph           \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bo          \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bs         \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bt        \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b        \b\b\b\b\b\b\b1      \b\b\b\b\b\b      \b\b\b\b\bp    \b\b\b\br   \b\b\bo  \b\bt\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b$enable mode permit ingress-type iphost 1 prot           \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bo          \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bc         \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bo        \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bl       \b\b\b\b\b\b\b       \b\b\b\b\b\bw     \b\b\b\b\be    \b\b\b\bb   \b\b\b   \b\bt\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b$e permit ingress-type iphost 1 protocol web t           \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\be          \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bl         \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bn        \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\be       \b\b\b\b\b\b\bt      \b\b\b\b\b\b
EOF;

// converting the line into an array of char
// str_replace here is useful to turn \b into one character,
// it will be easier to parse the string as an array below
$log_array = str_split(str_replace("\b", chr(8), $log_line));
$final_log_array = [];

// Now, we parse the log line char by char
foreach ($log_array as $char) {
    // if we encountered a '\b' character, we "pop"
    // the last character from the array
    // otherwise, we "push" the character to the array
    if ($char == chr(8))
        array_pop($final_log_array);
    else
        array_push($final_log_array,$char);
}

// Time to see the result
$final_log_line=implode($final_log_array);
echo "<pre>";
echo "Expected line:\n";
echo "OLT-235(gpon-onu-mng)#security-mng 1 state enable mode permit ingress-type iphost 1 protocol web telnet\n";
echo "Result line:\n";
echo $final_log_line . "\n";
echo "Line with all \b and double spaces removed:\n";
echo preg_replace("/(?:\\\b|\s\s)+/", "", $log_line);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

(You can try this code with [PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/).)

The output shows:

```
Expected line:
OLT-235(gpon-onu-mng)#security-mng 1 state enable mode permit ingress-type iphost 1 protocol web telnet
Result line:
OLT-235(gpon-onu-mng)#$e permit ingress-type iphost 1 protocol web telnet
Line with all \b and double spaces removed:
OLT-235(gpon-onu-mng)#security-mng 1 state enable mode permit ingress-type iph$g 1 state enable mode permit ingress-type iph os t1pr ot$enable mode permit ingress-type iphost 1 prot oc ol  w eb  t$e permit ingress-type iphost 1 protocol web t el ne t
```

You can see that the first attempt truncate the beginning of the line, while the second one leaves you with sequences like `protocol web t el ne t` you won't be able to clean programmatically.

IMHO, if I didn't make a mistake here, you should look for the root of this behaviour. Bug report?

Comment: this solution has less effect as with /\s\s|[[:^print:]]/, the problem is that backspace char should really mean a literal backspace, as you can see in the output looks like the limit of characters is exceeded and then the pointer need to adjust the frame with backspaces.

Comment: Yes I see and wanna thank by your good will, but this does not solve the problem. So let me reformulate my question to you, you know how I substitute the backspace char with a literal backspace removing the last character before him?

Comment: @PedroPILLA, as you can see in this answer, I was only able to show that it might not be the good way to clean the mess. Sorry, I don't know this library.

Comment: Yeah I think it is very hard, I tried manually removing every \b and removing the last char but there are more backspaces than should have. Other way could be after removing \b and spaces, split the string by $ and then merge in some way overwriting the repeated parts http://codepad.org/IJkNoVvS

Comment: @PedroPILLA Then how will you deal with `prot oc ol  w eb` ? What spaces will you remove?

Comment: Yes I have to deal better with spaces, not just removing double spaces will solve. I dont think it is a phpseclib issue because when I shell_exec a tcl script for example I have same result, looks something with the device shell. Anyway, thank you by your effort, mate!